# I want to iterate the component depending on user input

Tags: vuejs2

This code does not repeat the component only displays the number in text input... I want to repeat the component

```js
    var app= new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
      number:Number,
         },}
        );
```

```html
    <div id="app">
   <p>Enter the number you want</p>
    <input v-model="number"></input>
    <div v-for='i in number'>
       <span>{{i}}</span
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need a value in data, not a type. `number: ''` or `number:0`.
- Second, you need to convert the text to a number. `v-model.number`
  **edit**
- Third, close your `span` tag.

The *convert the text to a number* part is the main reason your code fails though...

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    number: '',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Enter the number you want</p>
  <input v-model.number="number"></input>
  <div v-for='i in number'>
    <span>{{i}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```